# How to add options to a Symfony Form field?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, types

I am rather new to PHP & Symfony, and am struggling with the form options:

I have the following, simple code:

```
  //OnceType.php
class OnceType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('date', TextType::class, [
            "format" => "date"
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Once::class,
        'format' => "date",
    ]);
 }
}
```

I get an error because the `format` is not an option of `TextType`, but I cannot find a way to add my own options (But I know this is possible, from the others posts I read)

I have read a lot of other posts with similar issues, but cannot grasp how to do this (I tried the `setDefaults options`, but it didn't lead me anywhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to create a new custom extension which extends the TextType like this for example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TextTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['format'] = $options['format'];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'format' => null,
        ]);
    }

    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [TextType::class];
    }
}
```

Read more here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a call to $resolver->setAllowedTypes() in your configureOptions() method.

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#passing-options-to-forms

Answer (score -1):

thanks for your help

I tried to do that, but still get the same error:

```
class OnceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
        $builder
            ->add('date', TextType::class, ["format" => "date"])
        ;
    }

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Once::class,
            "format" => "date",
        ]);

        $resolver->setAllowedTypes("format", "string");
    }
}
```

EDIT: I think it is because the resolver there adds the options to form, instead of the option iteself ('date', the one added in buildForm)